# Interpreting a linear combination in different ways

Tags: vectors

If a point $p$ has an i-ward velocity of 1 meter per second and a j-ward velocity of 1 meter per second, then it will move from (0,0) to (1,1) in one second.
$$ (\vec i + \vec j )\cdot \delta t $$

If, on the other hand, it has an i-ward velocity of 2 meters per second for HALF a second, then replaced by a j-ward velocity of 2 meters per second for HALF a second, then it will ALSO move from (0,0) to (1,1) in one second.
$$ (2\vec i + 2\vec j )\cdot \frac{\delta t}{2} $$

(In the first case, the i and j components act simultaneously, in the second case they act sequentially.)

Given that $p$ goes from (0,0) to (1,1) in unit time in both cases but the paths by which it does so is different (the first path is of length $\sqrt2$ whereas the second is of length $2$), how come we never hear of this second type of linear combination? Taking into account time, the two types of linear combination seem to be conceptually different.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143148/discussion-on-question-by-pete-interpreting-a-linear-combination-in-different-wa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key insight is that velocity corresponds to displacement while *speed* corresponds to path length. Your two expressions give displacements, *not* path lengths:

- displacement = $\color\red{\text{average velocity}}$ $\times$ time elapsed

  in Scenario 1, displacement magnitude $=  \left|\color\red{(\vec i + \vec j)} \times t \right|=t\sqrt2 $

  in Scenario 2, displacement magnitude $=  \left|\color\red{\frac12(v_1+v_2)}\times t \right|=  \left|\color\red{\frac12(2\vec i + 2\vec j )}\times t \right|=t\sqrt2 $
- path length = $\color{violet}{\text{average speed}}$ $\times$ time elapsed

  in Scenario 1, path length $=  \color{violet}{\left|\vec i + \vec j \right|}\times t=t\sqrt2 $

  in Scenario 2, path length $=  \color{violet}{\frac12\left(s_1 + s_2 \right)}\times t =\color{violet}{\frac12\left(|2\vec i| + |2\vec j| \right)}\times t =2t$

Related: [Is arc length displacement or distance traveled?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4636531/21813)

Comment: ok, got it, thanks Ryang!